# PeerGuardian Installation (E: Unable to locate package)

Tags: package-management, software-installation

Following the instructions on their wiki (http://sourceforge.net/p/peerguardian/wiki/pgl-Install-DebianUbuntu/), I run into this error that it cannot find any of the PG programs to install. What am I doing wrong, how do I install PeerGuardian?

```
odroid@odroid:~$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jre-phoenix/ppa
[sudo] password for odroid: 
 This PPA provides offical packages of PeerGuardian Linux (pgl) for all supported Ubuntu series. This archive enhances http://moblock-deb.sourceforge.net, where I offer Debian packages for the current Debian series.

PeerGuardian Linux (pgl) is a privacy oriented firewall application. It blocks connections to and from hosts specified in huge blocklists (thousands or millions of IP ranges). Its origin seeds in targeting aggressive IPs while you use P2P. PeerGuardian Linux is actively developed. However the team is very small and with few spare time. Contributors are welcome! Check out http://peerguardian.sourceforge.net.

For Ubuntu hardy you will find the precessors of pgl here: nfblock/moblock, blockcontrol and mobloquer. They aren't developed any more.
 More info: https://launchpad.net/~jre-phoenix/+archive/ubuntu/ppa
Press [ENTER] to continue or ctrl-c to cancel adding it

gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmp023hq837/secring.gpg' created
gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmp023hq837/pubring.gpg' created
gpg: requesting key 9C0042C8 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: /tmp/tmp023hq837/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
gpg: key 9C0042C8: public key "Launchpad PPA for jre-phoenix" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1  (RSA: 1)
OK
odroid@odroid:~$ sudo apt-get update
Hit http://deb.odroid.in trusty InRelease
Hit http://deb.odroid.in trusty InRelease                                      
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Hit http://deb.odroid.in trusty/main armhf Packages                            
Ign http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease                         
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Ign http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty-updates InRelease                  
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                         
Ign http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty-backports InRelease                
Hit http://deb.odroid.in trusty/main armhf Packages                   
Ign http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty-security InRelease                          
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                         
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg                        
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                         
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty-updates Release.gpg                
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg                       
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty-backports Release.gpg              
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg                       
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty-security Release.gpg               
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg                       
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty Release                            
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg                                
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty-updates Release                    
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty-backports Release                           
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg                                
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty-security Release                            
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release                                    
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty/main Sources                                
Ign http://deb.odroid.in trusty/main Translation-en_US                         
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release                                    
Ign http://deb.odroid.in trusty/main Translation-en                            
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Sources                          
Ign http://deb.odroid.in trusty/main Translation-en_AU             
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release                        
Ign http://deb.odroid.in trusty/main Translation-en_US             
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Sources                            
Ign http://deb.odroid.in trusty/main Translation-en                            
Ign http://deb.odroid.in trusty/main Translation-en_AU             
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release                        
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty/main armhf Packages                         
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted armhf Packages                   
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release                        
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty/universe armhf Packages                     
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main armhf Packages            
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en_AU          
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en      
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Sources                  
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en_AU   
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main armhf Packages           
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en           
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en_AU     
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Sources                  
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Sources           
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main armhf Packages           
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted Sources     
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en           
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Sources       
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Sources                  
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main armhf Packages    
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main armhf Packages           
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted armhf Packages
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en           
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe armhf Packages
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main armhf Packages           
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Translation-en    
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en           
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Translation-en
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main Sources         
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted Sources   
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main armhf Packages  
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted armhf Packages
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main Translation-en  
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Sources          
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted Sources    
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Sources      
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse Sources    
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main armhf Packages   
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en_US        
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted armhf Packages
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en           
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe armhf Packages
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en_AU        
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse armhf Packages
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Translation-en
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Translation-en            
Ign http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en_US                      
Ign http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en_US                
Ign http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en_US                  
Reading package lists... Done                                                  
odroid@odroid:~$ sudo apt-get install pgld pglcmd pglgui
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package pgld
E: Unable to locate package pglcmd
E: Unable to locate package pglgui
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[I'm the maintainer of said ppa]:

When Launchpad builds a source package in a PPA, it creates binaries for i386 (x86) and amd64, but not for arm. (Source: help.launchpad.net/Packaging/PPA).

But there is a possibility to request community arm builds (dev.launchpad.net/CommunityARMBuilds), which I just did: https://answers.launchpad.net/launchpad/+question/261099

So hopefully they will show up soon, just check that link.

EDIT 2015-01-25: **armhf packages are now available for Vivid, Utopic and Trusty. Other dists will follow.** Just drop me a mail if there are any further issues.

Generally:
You can check the "Packages" file of the ppa for your arch to see if there are packages available. E.g. the following file is empty (=no packages currently for pgl on arm64):
http://ppa.launchpad.net/jre-phoenix/ppa/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-arm64/Packages

btw the original answer by Oli was wrong (still a big thank you and muru for the continued participation in this thread): the packages are indeed called pgld, pglcmd and pglgui. So the apt-get install command was correct. Only the source package is called pgl.

Answer (score 1):

[That repo](https://launchpad.net/~jre-phoenix/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) only has a `pgl` package. If you look at the [package files](https://launchpad.net/~jre-phoenix/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+sourcepub/3850710/+listing-archive-extra) you'll see it provides binaries for all those commands. That's all you need to install.

```
sudo apt-get install pgl
```

I should also add that this PPA only ships versions for lucid-trusty. If you're using something newer (eg 14.10), this won't work. [Talk to its maintainer](https://launchpad.net/~jre-phoenix).

Comment: `odroid@odroid:~$ sudo apt-get install pgl`
produces:
`E: Unable to locate package pgl`

Comment: Are you on 14.10? It only has versions for up to Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: @Oli There are several lines mentioning `ports.ubuntu.com` - perhaps the OP is on an architecture other than `i386/amd64`.

Comment: `Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS`, and it is some sort of `ARM` processor (but I thought the entire point of an OS was to deal with hardware differences)???

Comment: @muru Good spot.

Comment: @JonathonWisnoski It can deal with the differences (and *most* of the core Ubuntu software is ported). This isn't core software. This is something sitting in somebody else's repository. You're going to have to compile this for yourself, [per this document](http://sourceforge.net/p/peerguardian/wiki/pgl-Install-DebianUbuntu-Custom/). (Or beg the maintainer to add the relevant ARM build).

Comment: OK, um, in the future how do you tell if something will be compatible with arm or not? It is not like there appears to be any warning on their wiki. It was just "Ubuntu users do this to install".

Comment: In the case of Ubuntu's software, `apt-cache policy <package>` will tell you if something's available. For PPAs, visit their page and see if your architecture (run `dpkg-architecture`) has a build for you. x86 is still the most popular. People still assume you're using it.