# Unable to locate package for peerguardian

Tags: package-management, software-installation, ppa, arm

I wanted to install PeerGuardian in Kubuntu 17.10.1. I followed [this guide](https://sourceforge.net/p/peerguardian/wiki/pgl-Install-DebianUbuntu/#install-peerguardian-linux-pgl-on-debian-or-ubuntu-systems).

The commands were:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jre-phoenix/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pgld pglcmd pglgui
```

Tried that and got this error message:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package pgld
E: Unable to locate package pglcmd
E: Unable to locate package pglgui
```

Then I read somewhere that it was:

```
sudo apt-get install pgl
```

But I got this error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package pgl
```

I heard that I need something called `arm` which is not `x86` or `amd64` but I am not sure.

Comment: That [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~jre-phoenix/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) has no package for 17.10.1. That is why it's not working.

Comment: I dont think thats the issue because this os is based on ubuntus os, that would be silly if it was just a version mismatch.  im not the only one with this problem either https://askubuntu.com/questions/576203/peerguardian-installation-e-unable-to-locate-package/576207   I dont really no what an arm is though and im new to the hole ppa thing, but what I do know is there might be an updated way to install it.

Answer (score 3):

As commented by [user535733](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1008220/unable-to-locate-package-for-peerguardian#comment1632640_1008220), this PPA has no package for Ubuntu 17.10. You can check the supported Ubuntu versions on the [PPA page](https://launchpad.net/~jre-phoenix/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) by expanding *Technical details about this PPA* then clicking the dropdown list.

[image]

---

- The `Unable to locate package` error is shown when the requested package wasn't found in any package list.
- The package lists for a PPA are located in a subdirectory of `<repo-base-url>/dists/<ubuntu-code-name>/`.

As you can see on the [PPA page](https://launchpad.net/~jre-phoenix/+archive/ubuntu/ppa), under *Technical details about this PPA*, the repository base URL is http://ppa.launchpad.net/jre-phoenix/ppa/ubuntu. If you navigate to the [dists](http://ppa.launchpad.net/jre-phoenix/ppa/ubuntu/dists/) directory you'll wont find the `artful` (Ubuntu 17.10 code name) directory. That's why the `pgl*` packages are not known to the package manager.

---

I don't know why you think you need [arm](https://askubuntu.com/tags/arm/info) packages, but even if you do the PPA [provides](https://launchpad.net/~jre-phoenix/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+sourcepub/5705618/+listing-archive-extra) arm packages for the supported Ubuntu version.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1008349/225694) the PPA from your tutorial doesn't have packages for 17.10 (likely because the [last release](https://sourceforge.net/projects/peerguardian/files/PeerGuardian%20Linux/2.3.1/) was 2015-11-17) and while this limits your options, It doesn't rule out alternative methods. There are a couple of options.

1) Install the [debian package](https://sourceforge.net/p/peerguardian/wiki/pgl-Install-DebianUbuntu/#configure-your-system-to-know-about-the-packages) via `gdebi` or `aptitude` (which may do a better job of resolving dependencies)

2) [Compile from source.](https://sourceforge.net/projects/peerguardian/files/PeerGuardian%20Linux/2.3.1/)

**Note:** [Backing up](https://askubuntu.com/a/586172/225694) is a great way to make sure that you can test whatever you want without  having to resort to re-installation.

**Edit:** Before attempting to install anything it would be best to [confirm your architecture.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/189640/how-to-find-architecture-of-my-pc-and-ubuntu)